# Simplify MySQL subquery

Tags: mysql, subquery, simplify

How can I simplify this MySQL subquery?

```
Select * From tbl_sys_usuarios Where usr_CvePA IN 
(Select sub_usrCveDep From tbl_sys_usuarios_subalternos Where sub_usrCvePA IN (Select sub_usrCveDep From tbl_sys_usuarios_subalternos Where sub_usrCvePA='237'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to get rid of nested queries, this should work:

```
SELECT tsu.*
FROM tbl_sys_usarios tsu
INNER JOIN tbl_sys_usarios_subalternos tsus_a ON tsu.usr_CvePA = tsus.sub_usrCveDep
INNER JOIN tbl_sys.tbl_sys_usarios_subalternos tsus_b ON tsus_a.sub_usrCvePA = tsus_b.sub_usrCveDep
WHERE tsus_b.sub_usrCvePA = '237'
```

Comment: Works! Thank you very much Brian.

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer! I thing so...

```
Select * From tbl_sys_usuarios u
Join tbl_sys_usuarios_subalternos sub1 ON u.usr_CvePA=sub1.sub_UsrCveDep
Join tbl_sys_usuarios_subalternos sub2 ON sub1.sub_UsrCvePA=sub2.sub_UsrCveDep and sub2.sub_UsrCvePA='237'
```

Thank you!